# How to push 500KB length message into Service Bus Topic - Premium Tier?

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

I am trying to push approx. 500KB size message into Service Bus Topic. But I am able to push only up to 64KB and it is not showing any error and when receiver/subscriber received message it just have 64KB data. As per the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-premium-messaging), we should be able to push this size with premium tier.

Am I missing something here?

Below is my code to push message into Service Bus Topic:

```
 public async Task PublishMessageIntoEventTypeAsync(EventReceiver @event)
        {
            logger.LogInformation($"Start publishing notification event {@event.EventType} with requestID: {@event.EventMessage.RequestID} " +
                $"into service bus topic: {serviceBusConfigOption.TopicEventTypes}");

            var serviceBusClient = messageBusFactory.GetClient(serviceBusConfigOption.TopicEventTypes);

            await serviceBusClient.PublishMessageAsync(@event.EventMessage, @event.EventMessage.RequestID.ToString(), nameof(@event.EventType), @event.EventType);

            logger.LogInformation($"Successfully published notification event {@event.EventType} with requestID: {@event.EventMessage.RequestID} " +
            $"into service bus topic: {serviceBusConfigOption.TopicEventTypes}");
        }

/// <summary>
    /// AzureServiceBusFactory
    /// </summary>
    public class AzureServiceBusFactory : IMessageBusFactory
    {
        #region private fields
        private readonly object _lockObject = new object();
        private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, ServiceBusClient> _clients = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, ServiceBusClient>();
        private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, ServiceBusSender> _senders = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, ServiceBusSender>();
        private readonly ServiceBusConfigOption serviceBusConfigOption;
        #endregion

        #region ctors

        public AzureServiceBusFactory(IOptions<ServiceBusConfigOption> serviceBusConfigOption)
        {
            this.serviceBusConfigOption = serviceBusConfigOption.Value;
        }
        #endregion

        #region public methods
        /// <summary>
        /// Get ServiceBusClient
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="senderName"></param>
        /// <returns>IMessageBus</returns>
        public IMessageBus GetClient(string senderName)
        {
            var connectionString = serviceBusConfigOption.ConnectionString;

            var key = $"{connectionString}-{senderName}";

            if (this._senders.ContainsKey(key) && !this._senders[key].IsClosed)
            {
                return AzureServiceBus.Create(this._senders[key]);
            }

            var client = this.GetServiceBusClient(connectionString);

            lock (this._lockObject)
            {
                if (this._senders.ContainsKey(key) && this._senders[key].IsClosed)
                {
                    if (this._senders[key].IsClosed)
                    {
                        this._senders[key].DisposeAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                    }

                    return AzureServiceBus.Create(this._senders[key]);
                }

                var sender = client.CreateSender(senderName);

                this._senders[key] = sender;
            }

            return AzureServiceBus.Create(this._senders[key]);
        }
        #endregion

        #region protected methods
        /// <summary>
        /// Create ServiceBusClient
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="connectionString"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        protected virtual ServiceBusClient GetServiceBusClient(string connectionString)
        {
            var key = $"{connectionString}";

            lock (this._lockObject)
            {
                if (this.ClientDoesnotExistOrIsClosed(connectionString))
                {
                    var client = new ServiceBusClient(connectionString, new ServiceBusClientOptions
                    {
                        TransportType = ServiceBusTransportType.AmqpTcp
                    });

                    this._clients[key] = client;
                }

                return this._clients[key];
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region private methods
        /// <summary>
        /// Check ClientDoesnotExistOrIsClosed
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="connectionString"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private bool ClientDoesnotExistOrIsClosed(string connectionString)
        {
            return !this._clients.ContainsKey(connectionString) || this._clients[connectionString].IsClosed;
        }
        #endregion

    }

/// <summary>
    /// AzureServiceBus
    /// </summary>
    internal class AzureServiceBus : IMessageBus
    {
        #region private fields
        private const string ContentType = "application/json";
        private readonly ServiceBusSender _serviceBusSender;
        #endregion

        #region ctors
        internal AzureServiceBus(ServiceBusSender serviceBusSender)
        {
            this._serviceBusSender = serviceBusSender;
        }
        #endregion

        #region public methods
        /// <summary>
        /// Publish message into Service Bus Topic 
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
        /// <param name="message"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public async Task PublishMessageAsync<T>(T message)
        {
            var serviceBusMessage = new ServiceBusMessage(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message.AsJson()))
            {
                ContentType = ContentType
            };
            await this._serviceBusSender.SendMessageAsync(serviceBusMessage);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Publish message into Service Bus Topic 
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
        /// <param name="message"></param>
        /// <param name="messageId"></param>
        /// <param name="filterPropertyName"></param>
        /// <param name="filterPropertyValue"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public async Task PublishMessageAsync<T>(T message, string messageId, string filterPropertyName, string filterPropertyValue)
        {
            var serviceBusMessage = new ServiceBusMessage(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message.AsJson()))
            {
                ContentType = ContentType,
                MessageId = messageId,
                CorrelationId = filterPropertyValue
            };
            serviceBusMessage.ApplicationProperties.Add(filterPropertyName, filterPropertyValue);

            await this._serviceBusSender.SendMessageAsync(serviceBusMessage);
        }
        #endregion

        #region internal methods
        internal static IMessageBus Create(ServiceBusSender sender)
        {
            return new AzureServiceBus(sender);
        }
        #endregion

    }
```

Service Bus Topic - Max message size is 1024KB:

[image]

Comment: In standard tier, max size is 256KB only. If you have Premium tier, it can be up to 100MB.

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran yes! I am using Premium tier, but I am not able to push even 500KB size message.

Comment: You should set the property `MaxMessageSizeInKilobytes` , [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.servicebus.administration.createtopicoptions.maxmessagesizeinkilobytes?view=azure-dotnet), this should be done at the time of Topic creation itself, not afterwards.

Comment: correction, the Azure portal even allows to increase max message size for _existing_ queue or topic.

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran Yes! I tried that as well, and also updated the same in the question body. Currently I have set the max message size1024KB, but still I am not able push 500KB message.

Comment: Do you receive some error? If so, which one exactly?

Comment: @kosist No, I am not getting any error, it just simply accept up to 64KB message and rest got skipped.

Comment: That is weird. B/c when size limit is exceeded, then "Incoming messages that exceed these quotas are rejected, and an exception is received by the calling code." (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-quotas). So either you do not catch that exception, or you send some different payload than you expect to send.

Comment: you should have received Exception [MessageSizeExceededException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.messagesizeexceededexception?view=azure-dotnet), if that was the reason. may be there is some other issue on _receiving_ side that it truncates to 64kb.

Comment: @RakeshKumar, how did you check size of the received message? Did you check it on receiver side, or checked message stored in the queue (on Azure portal), while message was not read/received yet?

Comment: @kosist, I am checking the message size at receiver side(Service Bus Topic Subscriber). Now I am able to see the exception(after adding the try catch block). The message was exceeding the defined limit(I have set max message limit 1024KB), After increasing the max message size I am able to receive actual message. Thanks! for your suggestion and help.